# Prove or disprove the axiom of pairing impllies the weak axiom of pairing.

Tags: set-theory

I'm currently reading *Introduction to Set Theory* by Karel Hrbaceck and the laid-out doubt in the question's title arose over the "remark" the author made after stating the *axiom of pairing.*

> **The axiom of pairing** For any $A$ and $B$, there is a set $C$ such that $x\in C$ if and only if $x=A$ or $x=B$. "So $A\in C$ and $B\in C$," and there are no other elements of $C$.

**My doubt**. Intuitively, at least for myself, it wouldn't make sense that $A\in C$ and $B\in C$ necessarily follows from the condition $x=A$ or $x=B$. It might as well be that $A\in C$ and $B\notin C$ (for instance), right? Then, **the axiom of pairing does not always imply that $A\in C$ and $B\in C$.** (My choice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you just have a small misunderstanding when interpreting the statement---in symbols, the intended meaning is:
$$
x \in C \iff (x = A \vee x = B).
$$
In particular, if $x = A$ then certainly $x = A \vee x = B$, and thus $x \in C$ (i.e. $A \in C$). Likewise for $B$, so no, the axiom of pairing "does always imply that $A \in C$ and $B \in C$".

I think your interpretation has followed from misinterpreting the "$\iff$" as an "$\implies$".

Comment: You're probably right. Cheers!